How to make custom notifications on Windows/Linux on Flatter?
I need to make custom notifications like in the screenshot (telegram notifications). I tried to use the following libraries: windows_notification, local_notifier. But they didn't suit me because they use native Windows notifications, which don't suit me. Can you tell me if there are any solutions?

